# GLM Library in OpenGL ES

Tags: java, android, glm-math

I haven't programmed in Java for 3 years and because of that I'm kinda clumsy with it.

The problem is that i have to develop a Android App with OpenGL ES. Now I'm wondering how I should do my 3D maths. In my C++ games i always used glm ([glm.g-truc.net](http://glm.g-truc.net)) but this is a C library.

I've seen some posts about this topic which said, that glm is also very good to use in OpenGL ES. But here's the point. I may sound nooby, but i have no clue how to use glm in my OpenGL ES application that's implemented with JAVA. Do I have to use JNI to be able to use that library?

Comment: You know, you can develop Android applications in C++, right? Also, GLM is a C++ library, not a C library.

Comment: you mean with the native development kit? isn't it better to write in java?